# How to count how many ip in bash?

Tags: bash, ip, variable

Does anybody know how to count how many ip in bash?

For example:
Command:

```
root@ubuntu:~$ dig www.google.com A +short | grep -oE "\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b"
```

and for example I get

```
114.114.114.114
114.114.115.115
8.8.8.8
etc...
```

and I want to run a specific command to get:

```
N IPs found in DNS
```

(N is the number of IPs which found in the return)

also I want to divide these IPs to different varibles:

```
$a="114.114.114.114"
$b="115.115.115.115"
$c="8.8.8.8"
$N="x.x.x.x"
```

Does any body know how to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an array to fetch the results in and use the number of array elements to display the `N IPs found in DNS` line. It is also possible to iterate through the array or use specific elements from the array:

```
#!/bin/bash

myarray=( $(dig www.google.com A +short | grep -oE "\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b" ) )
echo "${#myarray[@]} IPs found in DNS"

for IP in ${myarray[@]}
do
    echo IP: $IP
done

echo "The third entry found in DNS is: ${myarray[2]}"
```

Answer (score 2):

To count the IPs just add `|wc -l` at the end of your command.

Comment: To explain, `wc` is the **w**ord **c**ount program.  Using the flag `-l` counts the number of **l**ines instead of the default.

Comment: @user1717828 you're correct, I'm sorry if I haven't explained `wc` but I always (which doesn't mean I'm right) assume that people is aware of `man` to learn more about the commands.